# DS18B20 responds with a precense pulse, but doesn't send data

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, stm32, sensor, communication

Pretty much the title. I used normal GPIO with direction flipping to do comms. The sensor pin is normally high (from the pullup), and gets pulled low in response to the reset pulse. The data however is all 1s which I assume to mean that the sensor isn't sending a response.

The circuit:
[image]

It's an STM32F030F4 running at 32Mhz.
Microsecond delay timer configuration:
TIM14
Prescaler: 31
Period: 65535
Clock-division: none
Auto-reload preload: enabled

The delay function:

```
void DelayUS(uint32_t US) {
  __HAL_TIM_SET_COUNTER(&htim14, 0);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim14);
  while (__HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim14) < US);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Stop(&htim14);  
}
```

The code:
https://glot.io/snippets/gtrixesowi

This is the main function:

```
test =  DS18B20_Reset();
if (!test) {
    DS18B20_WriteByte(CMD_SKIPROM);
    DS18B20_WriteByte(CMD_CONVERT);
    HAL_Delay(800);
}
test = DS18B20_Reset();
if (!test) {
    DS18B20_WriteByte(CMD_SKIPROM);
    DS18B20_WriteByte(CMD_RSCRATCHPAD);
    UByte = DS18B20_ReadByte();
    LByte = DS18B20_ReadByte();
}
```

The code execution goes into both if cases, and I get 255 for both `UByte` and `LByte`.